# getting error trying to connect proxy to pupeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, puppeteer

Im getting the error Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at http://lumtest.com/myip.json

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--proxy-server=191.243.218.249:53281']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate();
    await page.goto('http://lumtest.com/myip.json');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the prefered protocol before ip address and port.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--proxy-server=https://191.243.218.249:53281']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate();
    await page.goto('http://lumtest.com/myip.json');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: now im getting the  Error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED at http://lumtest.com/myip.json

Comment: Did you test it with another proxy address, for examples, with one listed in this page:  https://scrapingant.com/free-proxies/